# Инвертирование списка через рекурсивную функцию

Tags: списки, delphi, рекурсия

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать процедуру инвертирования списка с помощью рекурсивной функции. Например для списка типа:

```
TPListEl = ^TList;
    TList = recored 
      element: integer;
      next: TPListEl;
    end;

    var Start : TPListEl; // Глобальный указатель на начало списка

procedure recursionInvert(var Start : TPListEl);
    var NP : TPListEl;
  begin
    if Start = nil then
    begin
      Start := nil;
      exit;
    end;
    if Start^.next = nil then
    begin
      Start := Start;
      exit;
    end;
      NP := Start^.next;
      Start^.next := nil;
      recursionInvert(NP);
      NP^.next := Start;
  end;
```

Вот набросал. Инвертирует правильно. Но не могу придумать как теперь указатель на начало списка переставить на последний элемент исходного списка.
То есть вот это:

```
if Start^.next = nil then
    begin
      Start := Start;
      exit;
    end;
```

Отрабатывает как нужно, но потом на откатке старт опять же меняется и становиться опять таким каким и был в исходном списке.

Comment: Эээ...

    if Start = nil then
    begin
      Start := nil; {<--- зачем?}
      exit;
    end;
    if Start^.next = nil then
    begin
      Start := Start; {<--- а это??}
      exit;
    end;

Comment: По делу: пусть `recursionInvert` станет функцией, возвращающей указатель на голову нового списка.

---
А вообще, рекурсивное обращение списков допустимо **только** в учебных целях. Подумайте, что будет, если количество элементов в вашем списке — несколько миллионов. (Для маленьких объёмов данных список не лучше массива.)

Comment: @VladD Возможно и так, но это, скорее всего относится к произведениям фирмы Borland (намёк на tail call)

Comment: @alexlz: А Delphi умеет элиминировать хвостовую рекурсию? Не знал. В любом случае, в коде ТС рекурсия не хвостовая.

Comment: @VladD так и я не знаю. Я же писал, что "допустимо только в учебных целях" "скорее всего относится к пр. ф. Borland". Delphi как раз оттуда.

Comment: @alexlz: А, понял. Ну да, видно, что учебное задание, согласен, даже по языку и стилю кодирования.

Comment: да задание учебное. Правда уже сам докумекал))

Comment: > Подумайте, что будет, если количество элементов в вашем списке — несколько миллионов.
Нужно еще предусмотреть такой случай, когда последний элемент "случайно" указывает на первый :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
procedure recursionInvert(var Start : TPListEl);
  var NP : TPListEl;
begin
  if Start = nil then exit;
  if Start^.next = nil then exit;

  NP := Start^.next;
  recursionInvert(NP);
  Start^.next^.next := Start;
  Start^.next := nil;
  Start := NP;
end;
```

А вообще, лучше делать без рекурсии:

```
procedure iterativeInvert(var Start : TPListEl);
  var Last, Next: TPListEl;
begin
  if Start = nil then exit;
  Last := nil;
  while true do
  begin
    Next := Start^.next;
    if (Next = nil) then exit;
    Start^.next = Last;
    Last := Start;
    Start := Next;
  end;
end;
```